# Looping through array and add to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array:

```
array  = [ [1,2], [2,3], [33,33], [2l,2]  ]
```

and a model called numbers with columns `numbera` and `numberb`. I want to fill `numbera` with the first value in array and `number b` [sic] with the second value in array like this:

```
Numbers Table
numbera        numberb
1              2
2              3
33             33
21             2
```

How would I do this? This is what I am trying to do:

```
n = Number.all
n.each do { |x| i=0; x.update_attributes(numbera:array[i][0], numberb:array[i][1]);i=i+1}
```

but it is not working. The `i` value does not increment in my solution. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Your `i` is inside the loop's scope. Use `each_with_index { |x,i|` and drop your `i=0` and `i=i+1` statements.

Answer (score -1):

after playing around with it a bit more, here is what worked: ( i just used instance variables)

```
@i=0

n.each {|x| x.update_attributes(numbera:array[@i][0], numberb:array[@i][1]);@i=@i+1;}
```

Comment: This works, but a couple of points. You don't need an instance variable here, you just need a variable that is initialised outside of the loop e.g. `i = 0` would work fine. When you were initialising `i` inside your `each` loop then the variable was local to the block and so was being reset each time the block was called (leading to it being 0 each time.) All that said, an approach using `each_with_index` as suggested is much more idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: would i use the each_with_index on the array or the model ? , as i have two collections which i need to loop through - or would i need two each_with_index calls ?

Comment: also ive tried initiallized i=0 outside that dosn't work... it gives me: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass